# Dynamics CRM 365 with SharePoint 365 integration to Cloud Backup

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure, dynamics-crm

I faced a problem that my client need to backup whole data from his Dynamics 365 CRM which is integrated wih Sharepoint 365 Online. Anyone know a soultion for this kind of problem ?.

Micosoft Azure DRB Center is not an option we are looking for some other Cloud backups providers if is possible.